# PostgreSQL: function with array argument

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql

For the first time I'm trying to create function in PostgreSQL:

This function must accept parameter with array type. Array contains sequence of biginteger values. Size of array not arbitrary, but known in advance.

```
 create function get_total (cols ARRAY) returns biginteger AS
   $BODY$
       begin 
         // Some logics 
       end;
   $BODY$
```

Usage in query

```
 select 
     stats.value1, 
     stats.value2,
     get_total(array_agg(ARRAY[stats.value2, stats.value1])) 
 from stats;
```

It returns error:

```
 type cols[] does not exist
 SQL state: 42704
```

When I run in Select only  array_agg(ARRAY[stats.value2, stats.value1]),  I see, that array created successfully. So the problem in function parameter.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare the parameter as `bigint[]`, which reads an array of type `bigint` e.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_total (bigint[]) 
RETURNS bigint AS
$$
BEGIN
 -- your fancy logic goes here
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Function call:

```
SELECT get_total(ARRAY[1111111111111,1111111111111]);
```

An elegant alternative is to declare the parameter as `VARIADIC`. Doing so you may call your function with multiple parameters,e.g.:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_total (VARIADIC bigint[]) 
RETURNS bigint AS
$$
BEGIN  
 -- your fancy logic goes here
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Function call:

```
SELECT get_total(1111111111111,1111111111111,1111111111111);
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=33d34b7f0e5099e0785e226d97907702)

Comment: When I specify only type of parameter, how could I use it hereinafter (without name of parameter)? For example I was able to use it in LOOP like so: FOR col IN cols

Comment: @Andrew you can name the parameter if you want, or use `$1` to access it, where 1 means the first parameter. In [my db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=33d34b7f0e5099e0785e226d97907702) I used it within a query. Can you see it?

Comment: @Andrew I believe this the third column of this fiddle might clarify things a bit: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1ff83452f3ff3bdf03e5de223a56ef54

Comment: Thank you, now always is clear

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `cols ARRAY` is the same as `cols[]` and means “an array with elements of type `cols`”. That's why you get that error message for the function definition.

If the element type is `bigint`, the function should be defined as

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_total(cols bigint ARRAY) RETURNS bigint
```